# Laravel webserver css and js files not refected

Tags: laravel, webserver

Hello my favourite community,

I have my own webserver inside my home network behind a UTC (hardware firewall).

When I open the server under 192.168.x.x the laravel app gets displayed perfectly.

As soon as I try to access my Laravel App from the outside world via NAT / portforwarding

I cannot see the css and js files.

The console showing me:

```
Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT                   app.css:1
Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT                   app.js:1
Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT                   192.168.1.220/img/favicon.ico:1
```

please check for yourself

the domain is

```
http://offline.vision
```

alternatively

```
https://prnt.sc/s28hvm
```

Yes I am still having issues with SSL which cannot be installed.

I think this has to do with some file pointing to 192.168.1.220 instead of the domain.

I wonder where I can change these setting.

Comment: `APP_URL` in your `.env` file. (Might need to run `php artisan config:clear` after making changes)

Comment: that doesnt help